# C++ 2D Vector initialization with another vector

Tags: c++, vector

```
vector<vector<double>> weights
{
    {1},
    {1}
};
```

Above is my code to make a 2x1 vector each holding 1.
I would like to make a matrix of 2xN that I could use to multiply with that vector.
I have seen other stackoverflow questions that talk about creating matrices, and most of the ones I've seen are with fixed values, or user input.

But what I would like to do, is initialize the entire first column of N length with 1s, and the initialize the entire second column with a second vector I already have.

I am unsure how in C++ I could accomplish this. I'm way more familiar with R, and in R this is a pretty simple task. Any thoughts or guidance?

Comment: similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68292153/create-a-2x1-vector-for-matrix-multiplication. Also here it is unclear what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
std::vector<int> vinner {
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
};

std::vector<std::vector<int>> v {
    std::vector<int>(10, 1),
    vinner
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (auto i : v) {
        for (auto j : i) {
            std::cout << j << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ clang++ -o vect vect.cpp -std=c++17
$ ./vect 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: So I've gotten this part done, by doing something very similar to what you did, except i just made a vector of ones, and put that as the first argument for the matrix. But now in this form I'm unsure how to access elements in an efficient way to multiply them.